# Finding limits, one sided limits.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this problem involving limits.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}   e^{\frac3{2-x}}  \\ \lim_{x\rightarrow2^+} e^{\frac3{2-x}}$$

I need some help on how to solve these to limit questions. I know plugging in two directly won't work. I tried some math tricks such as multiplying the exponent by $(2 - x)$, but I then end up getting the same answer for both question. This makes me think what if the

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} e^{\frac3{2-x}}$$

did not exist hypothetically. How would you then know this. I must solve this without drawing a graph. Any suggestions on how to go about solving this question ?

Comment: sorry for my notation. > in this case mean approaches.

Comment: You're trying to find $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}e^{3(2-x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}e^{2-x}$, correct? But in any case, I don't see why you state that $\lim\limits_{x\to2}e^{2-x}$ may not exist, since $\exp$ and $x\mapsto 2-x$ are both continuous over $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Yes but 3(2-x) for both

Comment: plugging in 2 works, the limit is $e^0=1$. Did you mean a different question, do you have a typo, why do you think the limit won't exist?

Comment: I think the asker may have meant to ask about $\;\lim\limits_{x\to\pm2} e^{3/(2-x)}\;$ , otherwise the two sided limits don't really matter here.

Comment: sorry. I saw the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
Try to determine something simpler, what are the following limits equal to? $$\lim_{x\to 2^+} \dfrac3{2-x} \qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to 2^-} \dfrac3{2-x}.$$

I've made below a graph of the function $x\mapsto\tfrac{3}{2-x}$:
[image]
As we approach $2$ from the left (i.e. $\color{darkmagenta}{x\to2^-}$) the values of our function go to infinity. But as we approach $2$ from the right (i.e. $\color{green}{x\to2^+}$) the values of our function go to *minus* infinity.

Comment: sorry. I need an explanation for that as well. One sided limits in general.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.

Comment: @rert588 Is it now clearer?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so muck.

Comment: @rert588 Can you now conclude what the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}e^{3/(2-x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}e^{3/(2-x)}$ will be?

Comment: Yes but shouldn't the asymptote be on x = -2

Comment: sorry. You are correct.

Comment: No wait. Positive q value, shifts the graph to the left.

Comment: @rert588 The function is discontinuous at $x=2$, i.e. when $2-x=0$. Do you know how to conclude then the values of the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}e^{3/(2-x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}e^{3/(2-x)}$?

Comment: i get it now. It's so cool.